# what is _hasConnectPatch in http.ServerResponse.prototype

Tags: node.js

I am looking the patch.js in connect module. There are some code as follows:

var http = require('http')
  , res = http.ServerResponse.prototype;

...

if (!res._hasConnectPatch) {
....

here what is the _hasConnectPatch property ? it is not in the description of the API doc in the node.js org. 
where can I find the description of _hasConnectPatch ?

Answer (score 0):

it's a boolean flag that avoids applying the code in [patch.js](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/patch.js) twice. `patch.js` provides "header sent" flag.

If you look at the comment just before the `if` in the [code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/patch.js) you'll see `// apply only once` and near the end of the file :

```
res._hasConnectPatch = true
```

It's not in node docs because it's a [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) extension.